# External audio enclosure transfer to local

Tags: audio, import

I am trying to find a way of easily importing external audio urls (podcasts) into my private blog. I have the external url as part of the enclosure but I want to be able to download it (either as part of FeedWordPress) or automatically. Currently, if I wanted to host the file locally I would need to save the file to my computer and then upload it via the Media uploaded. This is rather tiresome. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried putting the url in an anchor? `<a href="https://sub-domain.domain.com/path/to/file.mp3">file.mp3</a>`

Comment: Thanks but I really do want to import the audio and not leave it on another website...

Comment: You said you want to be able to download it. You're not very clear as to what your objective is. BTW, what is an enclosure as it pertains to your situation?

Comment: So the plugin imports data from a feed, inclulding the enclosure url (that is the the actual mp3 url) but it doesn't download the file. I want to automatically download the audio file.

Comment: I assume you have no control of said feed. You'll need to use software like wget or HTTrack or an extension like downthemall for Firefox. Good luck.